# Best link checking site?

Tags: website

We have a few sites that have affiliate links which are redirected from a tracking site to the merchant. Is there any sites that offer a service to check site links and whether they redirect correctly?

I am also asking this question separately on stackoverflow on how best to code this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://mon.itor.us/

Answer (score 0):

A bash script with wget ou curl lib ?